# Django "is not JSON serializable" - ajax, views.py - How to implement?

Tags: python, ajax, json, django, serialization

I have read the documentation, but I am not exactly sure how to implement `serializer.serialize` for JSON objects in my view.py.  If anyone can help me understand this a little better.  I have the following code in my view.py:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def ProjDetails(request):
    proj_id = request.GET['proj_id']
    proj = Proj.objects.filter(id=proj_id)
    role_list = ProjRole.objects.filter(proj=proj)
    proj = {
        "proj": proj,
        "roles": []
    }
    for r in role_list:
         proj['roles'].append(r.id)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(proj), content_type='application/json; charset=UTF-8')
```

I am trying to call this with .ajax (I am still working on the ajax, so it probably is not right):

```
$('#proj_list #sel_proj').click(function(){
   $('div.sel').removeClass("sel");
   $(this).addClass("sel");

   var project_id = $(this).data('id');

   $.ajax({
       url:'../../proj_details',
       data: {proj_id: proj_id},
       // dataType: 'html',
       success: function(data){
           $('#proj_display').html(data)
       },
       error: function () {
           alert("Failed to find the project!")
       }
});
```

Once I get the JSON call to work, then I will focus more on the ajax.

Biggest problem, I am getting a 500 http error with:

```
TypeError at ../proj_details
[<Project: Example>] is not JSON serializable
```

I am using Django 1.7, but I even added `SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'` to my settings.py without any luck.  So I imported serializers from the django.core and tried to use `serializer.serialize`, but I am not understanding how to implement it I guess because my errors just keep getting worse. I have seen other posts with the same error, but still not understanding for my particular requirements.

+++++++++++++++ EDIT +++++++++++++++++++

So the only way I have been able to get this to work without multiple errors, circular errors, multiple argument errors, etc, is the following:

```
def ProjDetails(request):
    def date_handler(obj):
        return obj.strftime("%B %d, %Y") if hasattr(obj, 'strftime') else obj

        proj_id = request.GET['proj_id']
        proj = Proj.objects.get(id=proj_id)
        corp = Corp.objects.get(id=proj.corp.id)
        role_list = ProjRole.objects.filter(proj=proj).all()
        proj = {
        "proj": {
             'title': proj.title,
             'id': proj.id,
             'date': proj.date,
             'description': proj.description
        }
        "roles": [],
        "company": {
             'name': corp.name,
             'pic': unicode(corp.pic),
        }
    }
    for r in role_list:
         proj['roles'].append(r.name)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(proj, default=date_handler), content_type='application/json; charset=UTF-8')
```

The only thing I don't like about this is I actually have to manually pull what attributes I want from the model into the dictionary, instead of all the attributes being pulled from the model and then I can choose which ones I want to use in my templates. I would rather not have to pull everything like my example above.  The `'roles' = []` is giving me some hiccups too because I can't seem to get it to work when there are multiple roles for a proj object.

I like Eugene's method because it would be cleaner, but I can't seem to get it to work with the corp model.  The proj tables have a corp_id, yet I keep getting corp_id is not an attribute when I attempt it with using .value().get() for the proj object.  I don't understand how to implement grzgrzgrz3's answer either.  I usually work more with JS, HTML, and CSS, and I am new to Django/python for web development.

So any suggestions to make this more efficient would be great.  Thank!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer, as described up above.  This is what worked for me.

```
   def ProjDetails(request):
    def date_handler(obj):
        return obj.strftime("%B %d, %Y") if hasattr(obj, 'strftime') else obj

        proj_id = request.GET['proj_id']
        proj = Proj.objects.get(id=proj_id)
        corp = Corp.objects.get(id=proj.corp.id)
        role_list = ProjRole.objects.filter(proj=proj).all()
        proj = {
        "proj": {
             'title': proj.title,
             'id': proj.id,
             'date': proj.date,
             'description': proj.description
        }
        "roles": [],
        "company": {
             'name': corp.name,
             'pic': unicode(corp.pic),
        }
    }
    for r in role_list:
         proj['roles'].append(r.name)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(proj, default=date_handler), content_type='application/json; charset=UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Django model's instance can't be serialized, you should use values() method to retrieve dict instead of class instance. Also, you can use only() method to retrieve only id field for roles:

```
proj = Proj.objects.filter(id=proj_id).values().get()
role_list = ProjRole.objects.only("id").filter(proj__id=proj_id)
proj = {
    "proj": proj,
    "roles": role_list
}
```

Comment: Then I get a ValueError: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: `  Maybe this has something to do with actual data in the database?  I also saw something about using list().  Could this be necessary?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Now I get a AttributeError that says 'Proj' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that values() works only with QuerySet, I've edited answer again.

Comment: I really thought there was an easier way to do this.  Now I have a TypeError for the datetime.date, which I see is common.  I am trying to figure this out now.  I guess I don't understand why you mean by Django's model's instance can't be serialized.  Is there a link to documentation for this?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/serialization/#serializing-data

Comment: Actually no, I have already read all that.  Which has lead me here.

Comment: @CharlWillia6 I find it hard to believe that you've read that, since you don't seem to be doing any of it in your code. Where is your call to `serializers.serialize()`?

Comment: Seems that all you need to do is to convert date field to string

Comment: @Daniel Roseman - If you read what I wrote, I said I had tried using it but kept getting nothing but areas.  I removed it from my code so all I had was  the "is not JSON serializable" error and asked if anyone could help me understand how to implement serializers.serialize() - So I am sorry you find that hard to believe, but I stated in this post that I have read the documentation and other sources, and I don't understand it.

Comment: @Eugene Soldatov - Thank you for you help.  I am working on trying to figure that out too.

Answer (score 1):

Write custom HttpResponse and handle there all not serializable python/django objects.

```
class HttpJsonResponse(HttpResponse):
    content_type="application/json"


    def __init__(self,data):

        def json_serial(obj):
            """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""

            if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
                serial = obj.isoformat()
                return serial

        json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4, default=json_serial)
        super(HttpJsonResponse, self).__init__(json_data, self.content_type)
```

In the example function `json_serial` converting `datetime.date` object into string object which is serializable.

*UPDATE

You can mix both answers.

```
def ProjDetails(request):
    proj_id = request.GET['proj_id']
    proj = Proj.objects.filter(id=proj_id).values().get()
    corp = Corp.objects.filter(id=proj.corp.id).values().get()
    role_list = ProjRole.objects.filter(proj=proj).values().all()
    proj = {
        "proj": proj,
        "roles": role_list,
        "company": corp
    }

    return HttpJsonResponse(proj)
```

Make sure you are importing datetime module.

```
import datetime
```

instead datetime class

```
import datetime.datetime
```

Comment: Is there an example of implementing this in the view?  I still can't get passed the 'is not JSON serializable' error with this, or I get an error regarding isinstance needing 2 arguments.

Comment: I get this when using your example: `isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types`

Comment: Did you add your custom if statement in the `json_serial` function? If so, show it.

Comment: I edited my post above.  That is what I ended up with.  The only thing I don't like about it is that I am having to use .get(), and leaves me having to pull in all the variables from my model manually. So any advice on making it more efficient would be great.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot get the object.filter() methods to work.  I keep getting `'dict' object has no attribute 'corp'`. So then I changed it to proj.corp_id, and I still get a comparable error.  Then I tried changing to get(), all(), etc, to try different variations, and I can't get it to work.  I don't really know why.

Comment: Well i do not know why but i post wrong code. Check it now